# Why this foreign key is not working for delete action in knex?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I have two tables, addresses and users, each user has an address, there is a column 'address_id' in table users that references a row in addresses table. But, when I delete a user, the address row is dont removed. Why?

table_users:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('users', function(table) {
        table.increments('id')
        table.text('name')
        table.text('cpf').unique()
        table.text('email').unique()
        table.text('pass')
        table.text('phone')
        table.timestamp('last_access').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
        table.timestamp('deleted_at').defaultTo(null)
        table.integer('address_id').unsigned()
        table.foreign('address_id').references('addresses.id').onDelete('CASCADE')
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('users')
};
```

table_addresses:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('addresses', function(table) {
        table.increments('id')
        table.text('street')
        table.text('number')
        table.text('complement')
        table.text('city')
        table.text('state')
        table.text('country')
        table.timestamp('last_access').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
        table.timestamp('created_at').defaultTo(knex.fn.now())
        table.timestamp('deleted_at').defaultTo(null)
    })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('addresses')
};
```

del function:

```
const del = (req, res, next) => { // TODO: colocar transaction aqui também
        knex('users').where({
            id: req.userData.id
        }).first().del().then(r => {

            if (!r) {
                throw new CompleteError('Falha ao deletar usuário.', 400)
            }

            res.status(200).json({
                sucess: true,
                data: {
                    message: 'Usuário deletado com sucesso.'
                }
            })
        }).catch(e => {
            return next(e)
        })
    }
```

Comment: If you are using SQLite3 iirc you need to setup some pragma to support foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current definition, the reference works backwards, that means that when ever you delete an **address**, it will delete the referenced user.

If you want that whenever you delete a **user** it will delete the address, you need to add a reference in **addresses** table to a user with `onDelete('cascade')`.